# Use input from other function (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, tdd

I'm really new into Python and english isn't my first language so please be nice to me.

How can I use input from another function?
The problem is that I have to  use TDD and my tests for malt_choice passed so I would like to keep that function if it's possible. Thanks!

```
def add_malt_menu():
    print('=' * 24)
    print("""
1. CaraRuby-Malt
2. Crystal-Malt
3. PaleAle-Malt
4. Pilsner-Malt
5. Return to main menu""")
   print('=' * 24)

>>>I would like to use the input from malt_choice here<<<

         pseudocode
         if input from maltchoice ==1:
             blablbla
         elif: input from maltchoice ==2:
         blablabla

def malt_choice():
    return input()
```

Comment: You don't want to call `malt_choice` in `add_malt_menu` again?

Comment: Yes I want to use the input from malt_choice in the add_malt_menu :)